# Error MongoError: Can't extract geo keys

Tags: mongodb

Estoy intentando insertar en una base de datos mongo un objeto GeoJSON

```
{ 
  name: "cancha de san lorenzo", 
  date: new Date(1489203188492), 
  loc: { 
      type: "Point", 
      coordinates: [ 19.3096246, -99.6301335 ]
  }
}
```

a través de la siguiente instrucción:

```
db.getCollection('places').insert(    { 
      name: "cancha de san lorenzo", 
      date: new Date(1489203188492), 
      loc: { 
          type: "Point", 
          coordinates: [ 19.3096246, -99.6301335 ]
      }
    })
```

Y obtengo el error:

*Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('58c37268cd95e4ab375a0ea1'), name: "cancha de san lorenzo", date: new Date(1489203188492), loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 19.3096246, -99.6301335 ] } }  longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 19.3096 lat: -99.6301*

¿Que podría estar pasando?

Comment: Parece que el error es bastante explícito: *"longitude/latitude is out of bounds"*.

Comment: Fíjate si esas coordenadas están en el orden correcto coordinates: [ Longitud, Latitud ] y no al revés

Comment: Es el problema de todos los cuervos, no poder referenciar ese punto correctamente :-)